# Show overlay and related image that is clicked on thumbnail

Tags: jquery, html, css

[DEMO fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6xc1d92k/14/)

JQuery

```
var thumb = $('.thumbContainer').find('.thumb');
  thumb.on('click', function(e){

    $('body').addClass('sidePanelOpen');
     var newimgsrc = $(this).data('img');
    $('.largeImgPanel').find('.lgimage').css("backgroundImage", "url("+ newimgsrc +")");
  });

  $('.sidePanelOpen #overlay').click(function(e){
    $('body').removeClass('sidePanelOpen');
  });
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="post">
    <div class="imageContainer">
      <div class="bigimg" style="background-image: url('http://www.cuteheaven.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/kitten-III.jpg');">
      </div>

    <div class="thumbContainer">
      <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="thumb" data-img="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/small-kitten-13447096.jpg" style="background-image: url('http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/small-kitten-13447096.jpg'); vertical-align: middle; width:100px"></div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="thumb" data-img="http://www.dumpaday.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/small-kitten.jpg" style="background-image: url('http://www.dumpaday.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/small-kitten.jpg'); vertical-align: middle;"></div>
        </a>
      </li>

    </ul>
    </div>
<div class="largeImgPanel">
  <div style="z-index: 9200">
    <div class="lgimage" style="background-image: url('___');"></div>
</div>
</div><!--./lg image panel-->
<div id="overlay"></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#overlay{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.sidePanelOpen #overlay{
  opacity: 0.9;
  visibility:visible;
  z-index: 9000;
}
.sidePanelOpen .largeImgPanel{
  background: red;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

    .bigimg{
      height: 250px;
      width: 250px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    display: inline-block !important;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ececec;
    transition: box-shadow .3s;
    }  

    .thumb{
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #999999;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    }
```

The big image area and thumbnail area - when user clicks on image, it would show overlay and image in src in full width 800px instead of background image.

Have been struggling to make alert appear but nothing happens. The problem is that jquery doesn't do anything. Tried on clicking on image and it didn't do anything. Also, not sure how to replace the src instead of css backgroundImage.

**Update**
Seems like if i place lgimagePanel outside the post div, it wouldn't behave as expected. Couldn't figure it out. With your help it is appreciated.

Comment: `.largeImgPanel'` , `.thumbnail` not appear included in `html` ?

Comment: @guest271314 - oops have corrected the code. thanks for pointing it out. The large panel would display large picture when click on thumbnail after overlay appear.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the following isn't necessary:

```
var thumb = $('.thumbContainer').find('.thumbnail');
thumb.on('click', function(e){
```

instead why not try the following:

```
$('.thumb').on('click', function(e){
```

You can then use $(this) to reference the element.

I'm not quite sure what to make of the rest. Do you want to replace the 'bigimg' with the thumbnail source?
That could be achieved by doing something like:

```
$('.thumb').on('click', function(e){  
    $('.bigimg').attr('data-img', $(this).attr('data-img'));
    $('.bigimg').attr('style', "background-image: url('" + $(this).attr('data-img') + "'); vertical-align: middle;");
});
```

... although I'm not sure why you have the url in the 'data-img' attribute.

Also, it's unclear to me when you want to show the overlay?
Also, you're missing the HTML element '#overlay'. It doesn't exist in your HTML nor is it build in the JS. You could add it as a div, fix the CSS up, and then toggle the visibility of it through jQuery's .toggle() function for instance.

**Update:**

Perhaps this fiddle is helpful to you (mostly changes to the JS):

http://jsfiddle.net/6xc1d92k/39/

Comment: yes i have corrected the post as well as fiddle. When click on thumbnail, overlay appears and then original picture appears on overlay. fiddle doesn't show overlay as on my local machine. toggle as in show and hide?

Comment: Actually data is not necessary but i wasnt sure how to extract the image from background image.